# None of the solutions worked for "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.util.HibernateUtil"

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo, javadb, glassfish-4.1

I am creating a hibernate web application which continuously gives the following error. Here is the full stack trace from Galss-fish server log.

```
> Info:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Info:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
WARN:   HHH000430: The DerbyDialect dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects instead
Info:   HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info:   No of Record From Dao: 1
Info:   No of Record From Dao: 1
Info:   No of Record: 1
Info:   Initializing ExportViewFactory with type={csv,excel,xml,pdf}
Info:   No LocaleResolver configured.
Info:   No of Record From Dao: 1
Info:   No of Record From Dao: 1
Info:   No of Record: 1


Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.util.HibernateUtil
    at com.dao.taskDao.getAllTask(taskDao.java:34)
    at org.apache.jsp.insertTask_jsp._jspService(insertTask_jsp.java:124)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I tried many of the solutions given in stack overflow and other sources for this problem. But it doesn't correct the error.

**HibernateUtil.java** File

```
package com.util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;


import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
            try {
                Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");         
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder sb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
                sb.applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
                StandardServiceRegistry standardServiceRegistry = sb.build();               
                sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(standardServiceRegistry);          
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                    System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
            }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

**Hibernate.cfg.xml** File

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/hrm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hrm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hrm</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping class="com.model.pojo.Task"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.pojo.Employee"/>
    <mapping class="com.model.pojo.Role"/>
    <mapping resource="com/model/pojo/Employee.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/model/pojo/Role.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/model/pojo/Task.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here are the database mapping files.

**Employee.hbm.xml** File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.model.pojo.Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">

  <meta attribute = "class-description">
         This class contains the employee details. 
  </meta>

  <id name = "eid" type = "int" column = "eid">
         <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <set name = "task" cascade="all">
         <key column = "eid"/>
         <one-to-many class="Task"/>
  </set>
      <property name = "ename" column = "employee_name" type = "string"/>
      <!--<property name = "rid" column = "roleid" type = "int"/>-->
  </class>

  <class name = "Task" table = "TASK">

      <meta attribute = "class-description">
         This class contains the task records. 
      </meta>

      <id name = "tid" type = "int" column = "tid">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>

      <property name = "tdescription" column = "task_description" type = "string"/>

      <id name="rid" type="int">
            <column name="role_id" />
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">role</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="role" class="com.model.pojo.Role" constrained="true"></one-to-one>

   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Role.hbm.xml** File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.model.pojo.Role" table="ROLE">
    <id name="rid" type="int">
            <column name="role_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
                <property name="rtitle" type="string">
            <column name="role_title" />
        </property>
                <one-to-one name="employee" class="com.model.pojo.Employee"
            cascade="save-update" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Task.hbm.xml** File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.model.pojo.Task" table="TASK"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the database table structure.

[image]

**Libraries** Used

[image]

I am very new to Hibernate.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: There should be another stacktrace that explains *why* `com.util.HibernateUtil` could not be initialized.